# Infinite recursion when emitting nested TableRow in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to pass a TableRow I've generated between stages of my pipeline, and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Forbidden IOException when writing to OutputStream 
[... exception propagation ...] 
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: 
com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor["file"]
->com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor["messageTypes"]
->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]-> 
[... many, many lines of this ...]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:733)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:88)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:717)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:717)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:142)
[... many, many lines of this ...]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:717)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:88)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)
[... snip ...]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:717)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
```

I'm constructing my TableRow recursively from a Google protobuf via its Descriptor - I traverse the descriptor depth-first recursively (since protobufs may have nested definitions) and build the TableRow as I traverse. Below is an excerpt from the TableRow creation class:

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    TableRow row = getTableRow(c.element());
    LOG.info(row.toPrettyString());
    c.output(row);
}

private TableRow getTableRow(TMessage message) throws Exception {
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    encode(message, row);
    return row;
}

private TableCell getTableCell(TMessage message) throws Exception {
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    encode(message, cell);
    return cell;
}

private void encode(TMessage message, GenericJson row) throws Exception {
    Descriptors.Descriptor descriptor = message.getDescriptorForType();
    List<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor> fields = descriptor.getFields();

    for (Descriptors.FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor : fields) {
        Descriptors.FieldDescriptor.Type fieldType = fieldDescriptor.getType();

        switch (fieldType) {
            case DOUBLE:
            case FLOAT:
            case INT64:
            case UINT64:
            case INT32:
            case FIXED64:
            case FIXED32:
            case UINT32:
            case SFIXED32:
            case SFIXED64:
            case SINT32:
            case SINT64:
            case BOOL:
            case STRING:
            case BYTES:
            case ENUM:
                if (fieldDescriptor.isRepeated()) {
                    List<Object> tableCells = new ArrayList<>();

                    tableCells.addAll((List<?>) message.getField(fieldDescriptor));

                    row.set(fieldDescriptor.getName(), tableCells);
                }
                else {
                    row.set(fieldDescriptor.getName(), message.getField(fieldDescriptor));
                }

                break;
            case MESSAGE:
                if (fieldDescriptor.isRepeated()) {
                    List<TableRow> tableRows = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Object o : (List<?>) message.getField(fieldDescriptor)) {
                        TMessage nestedMessage = (TMessage) o;
                        TableRow tableRow = getTableRow(nestedMessage);
                        tableRows.add(tableRow);
                    }
                    row.set(fieldDescriptor.getName(), tableRows);
                }
                else {
                    row.set(fieldDescriptor.getName(), getTableCell((TMessage) message.getField(fieldDescriptor)));
                }
                break;
            case GROUP:
                throw new Exception("groups are deprecated");
        }

    }
```

I believe that the TableRow is being created correctly because I've both tested this DoFn with some simple dummy data and looked at the result of the TableRow creation on a subset of my dataset (see the snippet above, where I `LOG.info` the result of the TableRow encoding), and the resulting TableRow seems to contain all of the data I expect with no extra fields.

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace? Also, more details about the recursion that generated the TableRow would be useful.

Comment: I've added a bunch more context to the question. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the stack trace and the code, it looks like something in the Protocol Buffer message may be self-referential. The JSON encoding is failing while following these references.

Looking at the code, my guess would be that you encountering an enum. If you look at the protocol buffer documentation of [getField](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder#getField-com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FieldDescriptor-) it says it returns an [EnumValueDescriptor](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.EnumValueDescriptor).

Looking at the EnumValueDescriptor, it has a link to the FileDescriptor, which has a link to EnumDescriptor which has a link to the FileDescriptor, which has a list of all the EnumDescriptors, which has a link to the FileDescriptor, etc.

If you handle the `ENUM` case specially (specifically to prevent protos from appearing as values in the JSON Map) it should fix your problem.

Comment: You got it! In my case I only care about the human name of the enum so I ended up using `EnumValueDescriptor#getName` to get it and stick it in the TableRow